# In Jmeter Scripting. Loop Controllers

Tags: jmeter

In Jmeter, If i want to put a "If Controller" in the middle of the script (say transaction 4) and then if condition is satisfied, the script should start executing from the start ie. 1st transaction.
If Condition Fails, the script must go to next step ie. transaction 5.

Is there any way to perform this ??

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller)

```
While Controller[condition]
    Transaction 1
    Transaction 2
    Transaction 3
    Transaction 4
Transaction 5
```

As long as the condition is true, while controller will execute all the transactions. When it fails, it will exit and execute Transaction 5.

Comment: Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I wanted to know, if i could use counter or counter function (_Counter) inside the while condition. ie. if i want to use counter to execute transaction 1-4 ten times and then go to Transaction 5.

Comment: @PuneetUniyal, yes. You can use counter. Check here - https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter

Answer (score 0):

I would set this up like:

- Txn 1
- Txn 2
- Txn 3
- Txn 4
- [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) with some condition

  - [Test Action Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) with `Go to next loop iteration` action
- Txn 5